# Can't solve 'passwd: Authentication token manipulation error' error

Tags: macos, unix, ssh

I'm trying to SSH into a Hills server for my local junior college. The system asks for my (current) UNIX password, however, when I enter the password I get the following error:

`(current) UNIX password:`

`passwd: Authentication token manipulation error`

I've included a photo of my terminal w/ the error:
[image]

I appreciate everyone's help, thanks in advance!

Comment: This has nothing to do with macOS, contact the administrator of the system you are connecting to.

Comment: Do you think I should try UNIX stack exchange? Thanks!

Comment: No, I think you should try what I said in my original comment.  There is nothing YOU can do about this problem.